# zend library for bar code image style in PHP

Tags: zend-framework, barcode

Is this possible to create bar code image like 'image1'. using Zend bar code library I create image(image2) but its diffrent. code mention below

```
$this->load->library('zend');
this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
$imageResource = Zend_Barcode::factory('code128', 'image', array('text' => "CMB5E65", 'barHeight'=> 50,'factor'=> 4), array())->draw();
imagepng($imageResource, $path);
```

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: There are many different symbologies for barcodes. Image1 is UPC, Image2 is Code 128B. You have to know your requirements before you choose a symbology. That is the start of a very long journey.

Comment: is there any library for Code Igniter to genrate bar code in UPC format, as per my r &d its not UPC format for example http://ahmed-badawy.com/site/api/upc-view @brian

Comment: For one thing, you can't display anything but numbers 0-9 in a UPC / EAN barcode. The barcode displayed in your example is Code 39 another symbology, entirely which is incapable of displaying lowercase letters. If you scan that barcode you get A%H%M%E%D B%A%D%A%W%Y, presumably because some application can be developed to recognize the percent sign as an escape character for lowercase. Once again, know your customer's requirements. If they need alphabetic or special characters in the barcode, you do not need UPC, you need another symbology. I recommend Code 128.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zend Framework manual lists the barcode symbologies supported on this page:

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.barcode.objects.html

The second barcode in your example will not fit in a UPC-A format, which is that used for your first example barcode. If your customer wants numeric data only, your code should look something like this:

```
$this->load->library('zend');
this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
$imageResource = Zend_Barcode::factory('UPC-A', 'image', array('text' => "689076996624", 'barHeight'=> 50,'factor'=> 4), array())->draw();
imagepng($imageResource, $path);
```

I am not sure if the '4' at the end is generated by the library. My guess is that you have to create the checksum yourself.

If, on the otherhand, your customer wants a barcode they can embed letters and symbols into, you have to use Code 128. On the Zend Framework page they mistakenly list the checksum as optional. I do not trust this.

A barcode font is not just like Helvetica or Times New Roman you have to write some code to get it to look like something that will scan and that your customers will like.